# Naudio crashed issue when using PlaybackStopped event

Tags: c#, naudio, naudio-framework

I am using Naudio to play sound but some time I am getting error of crash error in method where reader is wavestram list

Can we use some different way?

```
void wout_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (WaveStream ws in readers)         
        ws.Dispose();

    readers.Clear();
}
```

Error details:

[image]

Comment: Most likely disposing one of the streams removes it from the collection. Try `foreach (WaveStream ws in readers.ToList())` - this will enumerate over a copy of the list, and allow the underlying list to change.

Comment: Or, since callbacks are involved and threads, you might be having race conditions between threads, to solve that a lot more would have to be known about the code and a solid answer cannot be provided for the details shown so far. Most likely you would need to lock around manipulating and using the shared data.